# Magento 2.2.2 GetCacheKeyInfo() Error getId() on Null

Tags: cache, magento2.2.2, adminmenu

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in .../htdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Menu.php:233
 Stack trace: #0 .../htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Menu/Interceptor.php(37):
 Magento\Backend\Block\Menu->getCacheKeyInfo() #1
 .../htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1035):
 Magento\Backend\Block\Menu\Interceptor->getCacheKeyInfo() #2
 .../htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Menu/Interceptor.php(778):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getCacheKey() #3
 .../htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1093):
 Magento\Backend\Block\Menu\Interceptor->getCacheKey() #4
 .../htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(660):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() #5
 .../htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Ba in
 .../htdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Menu.php on line 233
```

Comment: try setup upgrade and cache clean???

Comment: @RonakRathod This seem to happen in a custom module backend page, when session expired I am missing something?